# ASP.NET CORE 6.0 - View engine can't find my cshtml views after upgrading

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

I upgraded my ASP.NET CORE 3.1 project to ASP.NET CORE 6.0 and now view engine can't find my cshtml views. I didn't change anything except upgrading .net packages. I have question if someone has experienced similiar behaviour ?

Below I added my mvc configuration in startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()

app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((host, builder) =>
            {
                builder.ClearProviders();
                builder.AddNLog("nlog.config")
                       .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Comment: Please write a title that summarizes your problem.

Comment: Can you share your Program.cs?

Comment: @YiyiYou I added my Program.cs